# Is it okay to keep EF Core DbContext alive for lifetime of a UWP desktop app?

Tags: c#, wpf, uwp, entity-framework-core

There seem to be certain benefits to having one DbContext instance alive in my app that cannot be achieved by disposing of the DbContext after every single DB transaction (save, delete, read, etc.).

I've come across many documents on the internet that sort of address my issue, but these documents seem to revolve around ASP.NET and other internet/server technologies. But with a simple app that users will be installing on their local machines, it just seem logical that there is a way to keep the context alive and avoid weird random issues. I'm sick of looking at "using" statements in every EF Core example I come across:

```
using (var context = new DbContext)
{
    /// Yada yada yada
}
```

The goal is to inject my service layer into my MainViewModel class. That service layer will initialize the DbContext and keep it alive as long as the MainViewModel is in memory (which will be until the app is closed by the user, since it is the MainViewModel after all).

Comment: Ef uses ado with sql server and keeping a dbcontext alive retains an open connection. This is bad if you have numerous users. If the database is on the users machine then that's one user per database and not a problem. If you know for sure you will only have a limited number of users then it's probably also not a problem. Connections are a limited expensive resource.

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: It uses SQLite. Also, my app is just a basic little note-taking app. You can list the users notes, create, delete, etc.. The typical things you do with a note-taking app. You can compare it to Google Keep. The data is saved locally on the user's machine. It is just that there are events (ChangeTracker.StateChanged, etc.) that I can subscribe to and other userful features that are only available if the context is persisted in memory. If the connection is opened and then immediately close, for example, after something as little as a "save" or "delete", then there are many benefits to EF lost.

Comment: Sqlite is as robust as it gets and although it can support multiple connections/sessions under the same thread it is wise to not over abuse it, so yeah, dispose it as soon as you can

Comment: One database per user and one dbcontext for everything. I can't think of a problem.